# назначение значений ключей в многомерном ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

как правильно создать многомерный массив с 2й вложенностью.Пробовал так, но получается немного не то, что надо

```
 $overall = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){            
                for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++){  
                     $overall[$i][] = $j;

                }            
            }
```

Получается

```
array(3) {
  ["1"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "5"        
  }
  ["2"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "5"        
  }
  ["3"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(18) "5"        
  }
}
```

Хотелось бы название ключей внутреннего массива задавать в цикле, что бы было по типу

```
 array(3) {
  ["1"]=>
  array(6) {
    [задано в цикле]=>
    string(3) "1"
    [задано в цикле]=>
    string(5) "2"
    [задано в цикле]=>
    string(6) "3"
    [задано в цикле]=>
    string(6) "4"
    [задано в цикле]=>
    string(6) "5"        
  }
  ["2"]=> .....
```

Comment: так Вы не сможете сделать. Слова "задано в цикле" у Вас являются ключом ассоциативного массива, а они (ключи) должны быть уникальны...

Answer (score 2):

dirk, Вы хотите, чтобы у вас ключом была фраза "задано в цикле"? Или Вы хотите ключ по какому-то шаблону создавать? Например так:

```
$overall = array();
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++) {
        $key = "key" . $j
        $overall[$i][$key] = $j;
    }
}
```